# Alter Snowflake Warehouse based on Explain Plan

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi Snowflake Community,

I would like to write a stored proc that takes Explain statement as an input and depending on the assignedbytes or number of partitions change the warehouse size accordingly.

Any sample code will be helpful.

I have written a sample code like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SAMPLE_PROC()
    RETURNS table()
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
res RESULTSET;
sql_query VARCHAR;
BEGIN
sql_query := 'EXPLAIN USING JSON
<my intended sql query that i want explain plan for>'
res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_query);
RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
$$
;

call SAMPLE_PROC();
```

Output:
After calling the stored procedure I am getting the explain plan output in the form of JSON.

Now how to modify this code or extend by creating another procedure to make a decision to alter warehouse depending on assignedbytes of explain plan output and then execute the actual query.

Thanks

Comment: Hi - please update your question with what you’ve managed to write so far and explain what issue you are facing

Comment: Updated the question with sample code

Comment: Hi - as you’re unlikely to find anyone on this site who’s just going to write the rest of the SP for you, you need to show at least an attempt at writing it for yourself and then explain where you are stuck. Do you not know how to process the result of the EXPLAIN, do you not know how to alter a warehouse, etc? The documentation for EXPLAIN includes a number of ways of processing the result